# Unable to access Javascript object property

Tags: javascript

I know this might be a noob question and that there are a lot of similar named questions but I couldn't find a solution which solved my problem.

I'm trying to access a simple nested JS object with the following code:

```
var test = '99999999';
var test_object = {};

test_object[test] = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
console.log(test_object);
console.log(test_object.test);
```

But for some reason I keep getting 'undefined' when trying to access the 'test' property.

I've created a simple fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nga7zqkf/

I just can't figure out why I can't access the 'test' property. Can someone please help me out here a bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below example

```
    var test = 99999999;
    var test_object = {};
    var test_object2 = {};

    test_object[test] = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
    console.log(test_object);
    console.log(test_object[test]);

    test_object2.test = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
    console.log(test_object2);
    console.log(test_object2.test);
```

Working example link  https://jsfiddle.net/nga7zqkf/3/

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. It is a wall of code with nothing resembling an explanation.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that your explanation shouldn't be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> var test = '99999999';
> test_object[test] = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
> ```

You never set the *test* property, you set the *99999999* property.

If you want to set the test property with square bracket notation, then the expression between `[` and `]` has to evaluate as `"test"`.

```
test_object["test"] = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
```

Or

```
var test = 'test';
test_object[test] = {"ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"};
```